# Android SQLite data Aceess of a null value attribute

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on my android project with SQLite database.
I need to get all the information of the perons who doesn't have a phone. I tried with following three ways but didn't provide the required data.
I have assign phone varchar(64), when create table.

```
select * from person where phone='null'
select * from person where phone=null
select * from person where phone=''
```

can anyone tell why is this happening and how can I get the information. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To query a null value use this sql statement:

```
select * from person where phone IS null
```